# Gerar diagramas UML a partir do código PHP?

Tags: php, diagrama

Há alguma maneira, software, IDE que gera diagramas a partir do código PHP, exemplo, tenho o projeto pronto em PHP, então ele pega meu código e gera os diagramas.

Como IDE uso o PHPStorm mas não sei se o mesmo tem tal  recurso.

Comment: Tem um [plugin](http://astah.net/features/php-view) para o Astah para esta finalidade.

Comment: Não sabia que o Astah tinha tal funcionalidade, obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: O phpstorm tem esse recurso

Comment: Consegui achar no PHPStorm obrigado @rray, sobre o do Astah, ele faz um inverso, você faz o diagrama e ele vai gerando o php do mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o @rray disse, o [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) tem esse recurso, é só selecionar as pastas ou arquivos que têm classes no `Project Explorer`, clicar com o botão direito e em `Diagrams` selecionar `Show Diagrams`, ou selecionar as pastas e pressionar `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+U`.